# What is fat tripe?

Tags: cut-of-meat, food-identification, offal

I was just in Santiago, Chile and had a mixed grill.  One of the tasty items was "Tripa gorda" or fat tripe.  But, I wasn't able to get a clear answer about exactly what fat tripe is.

Does anyone know what fat tripe is specifically?

Comment: Have you seen http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripa_gorda? It seems it was a bull's rectum. BTW, there are also other languages which have a name for the rectum which is a literal translation from "fat bowel", e. g. the German word Mastdarm. And before you think of being squeamish, remember what sausage casing is made of.

Comment: I love organ meats, and that makes me squeamish.  Rectum is just somehow more disgusting than intestines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the US the closest thing you could (easily) get would be "[Chitterlings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitterlings)" though this isn't *quite* correct since chitterlings are the small intestine, and *tripa gorda* is the large intestine.